# Angularjs Form Validate

Tags: angularjs, forms

How to validate a form in angularjs Form with a normal button and not with submit button.  I want to have same functionality that I got with the submit button. I am new to angularjs and I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326752/how-to-use-submit-button-to-submit-all-details-of-the-form-in-angularjs

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You want to tie an action like click to a button, there are lots of examples of such in the docs for angular.  A validate function is no different than any other action.    Also look at ngModel when reading the fine manual.

Comment: AngularJS does automatic validation on every keypress. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-click in your button so that it triggers function, in this case onClick(), in your controller.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="onClick()" >Normal Button</button>
```

And in the controller, you code your validation there.

```
$scope.onClick = function () {
    // Validation
    // then the rest
};
```